# Tag scores all zero on user's profile page

Tags: support, user-profile-page

Some users have zero score for all of their tags on their profile pages, even though they obviously have non-zero reputation:

[image]

Here are some examples of users: User [15662](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/15662/user15662?tab=tags), [24323](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/24323/user24323?tab=tags), [25993](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/25993/user25993?tab=tags), [27638](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/27638/user27638?tab=tags)

I'm not sure what the pattern is, hence the reference to it affecting only "some users." Although the above selection was somewhat arbitrary, it seems to mostly affect new users (with low reputation).

Comment: It looks to me that the boxed number only shows answers, but now questions, which would explain that all numbers show 0. The user didn't answered any questions yet.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

the boxed number shows the positive votes received by your answers. You can see it by placing the mouse cursor over the number for a couple of seconds:[image]

this is what happens after hovering the number 4.

In your screenshot the user has never answered any question, so all tags have zeros. He gained rep only with questions, not answers

Comment: That's true. It seems weird though to have a zero-score block when the tool-tip text gives a positive score for those tags in which you only asked questions. It does, however, make more sense now that I see all [tag badges](http://tex.stackexchange.com/badges?tab=tags) are associated with _answers_ only.